# What's the difference between scala.List and scala.collection.immutable.List?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala. And I noticed that `List` exists in both `scala` and `scala.collection.immutable`. At the beginning, I thought scala.List is just an alias for scala.collection.immutable.List. But later I found that:

```
scala> typeOf[scala.List[A]]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.List[A]

scala> typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.List[A]]
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = List[A]
```

As shown above, the `typeof` on these two `List`s give different results, which make me doubious about my judgement.

I would like to know:
Are scala.List and scala.collection.immutable.List the same thing? 
If yes, why `typeOf` gives different results as shown above?
If no, what are the differences?

Thanks!

Comment: API documentation is invaluable here: [`scala.List` is a type alias for `scala.collection.immutable.List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.package@List[+A]=List[A])

Comment: If you look at source code of package `scala` it has these two members `type List[+A] = scala.collection.immutable.List[A]` and `val List = scala.collection.immutable.List`. So yes... scala.List is just an alias for `scala.collection.immutable.List`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Thanks. But then why `typeOf` gives different results on these two types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Patryk mentioned in comment, it is an alias for `scala.collection.immutable.List`.

If you look at `scala\package.scala`:

```
  type List[+A] = scala.collection.immutable.List[A]
  val List = scala.collection.immutable.List
```

So fundamentally they are the same:

```
scala> implicitly[scala.List[Int] =:= scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]]
res19: =:=[List[Int],List[Int]] = <function1>

scala> :type List
scala.collection.immutable.List.type

scala> :type scala.collection.immutable.List
collection.immutable.List.type
```

What you are using is I believe `typeOf` from  `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._`. Which is a reflective representation of the type parameter and hence it gave you just `scala.List`  (which is correct behavior in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

`scala.List` is type alias for `scala.collection.immutable.List`

```
package scala

type List[+A] = scala.collection.immutable.List[A]
```

Anything under the `package` `scala` is by default available you don't have to explicitly import it.

As `List` is something which is widely used it makes perfect sense if it is available by default in the context rather than `importing`. That is why a type alias of the `scala.collection.immutable.List` is in package scala.

`typeOf` must be showing the higher preference package by default.